# When waited thread will be called if no other thread is available

Tags: java

I have only one Thread and moving that Thread in WAIT state. I do not have any other Thread. In this situation how can I notify or call the waited Thread?. Is it possible?

Comment: How are you "moving it"?

Comment: by calling wait() method

Comment: Are you doing a timed `wait()`?.

Comment: Did you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29

Comment: @Srinivasan "by calling wait() method" ... you are not very chatty, I see. In that case, your answer is: "call notify() method".

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply call notify() on your Thread object.

Comment: Calling wait/notify on a Thread instance is explicitly discouraged in the documentation because `join()` relies on it internally.

Answer (score 0):

U can access that through timed wait
or you can wake it by another thread but not by the same thread